# http-cache-semantics trivy error CVE-2022-25881 unable to identify transitive dependency causing this

Tags: node.js, trivy

We have a node js application which is failing due to a trivy scan error due to CVE-2022-25881 from http-cache-semantics.
We have gone through the package.json and couldn't find any dependency or transitive dependency which is referring to this library. Can someone please help us to point how could we address it?

```
 "dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.20.1",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"mongodb": "^5.0.1",
"passport": "^0.6.0",
"passport-azure-ad": "^4.3.4"
}
```

dockerFile

```
FROM node:16.19-bullseye-slim
RUN mkdir -p /.npm
VOLUME /tmp
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
# command to run when intantiate an image
CMD ["npm", "start", "--loglevel=verbose"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This vulnerability comes from `npm`
update `npm` to the latest version in your docker  should resolve this finding

https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/6148

Comment: Thank you for this. I am new to node js, could you please let me know how can I update NPM in my docker to latest? We are using github actions to build the docker image.

Comment: I was able to update npm by using "RUN npm -g install npm@latest" command in docker file. The issue got resolved.